SwiftUI draw function issue
I have the following requirement where I am trying to create an Image with Text under the picture/icon as such:
Image(
        
    size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60),
    label: Text("Set Paid").foregroundStyle(Color.white).font(.caption)
        
) { ctx in
        
    ctx.draw(
        Image("icon-dollar"),
        at: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 0),
        anchor: .top
    )
        
    ctx.draw(
        Text("Set Paid"),
        at: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 60),
        anchor: .top
    )

}

My issue is that the image:
ctx.draw(
    Image("icon-dollar"),
    at: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 0),
    anchor: .top
)

is 80x80.
Is there something i can do to "resize" that image with the ctx.draw function?!

Try using the draw function that takes a CGRect instead of a CGPoint, draw(_:in:style:):
ctx.draw(
    Image("icon-dollar"),
    in: CGRect(
        origin: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 0),
        size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
    )
)


AHHHHH Man ur a LIFESAVER!!!
